# Angular Posting to ASP.NET Core Web API returning failure

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

this is my code for the web api

```
 // POST api/Values
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post()
    {
        string user = new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(
                @"insert into Users
                select *
                from OPENJSON(@user)
                WITH( Username, Password, Email, Nickname, IsActive, Activation)");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", user);
        await SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
    }
```

and this is my code for angular js

```
data = JSON.stringify({Username: user, Password: pwd, Nickname: user, IsActive: '1', Activation: '2u4bubdub32939342'}); 
        $http.post('http://localhost:7792/api/values', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert( "failure message: " + data + " " +status+ " " +headers+ " " +config);
        });
        } catch (e) { alert(e.message); }
```

when i run it, i get the failure message. i already have COR enabled in the web apo

Comment: which angular version are u using

Comment: version 1, the get request works. only the post

Comment: What is the error message? Also, your comment seems to say the url should be api/todo, but your code is calling api/values.

Comment: oh sorry that was a mistake. ive updated the code

Comment: POST http://localhost:7792/api/values 500 (Internal Server Error)
VM864 signup:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:7792/api/values. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: Can you post your CORS settings?

Comment: Do you have 2 apps runing, one in port 7792 and another one in port 8100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your POST method should take a parameter, the user model, that you are correctly sending through Angular. I hope that this [example](http://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

after googling the web i added into my ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in startup.cs

```
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

and i also added into Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, .... in startup.cs

```
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Comment: Does it actually work now? Your posted API method is not taking any input, which seems... odd.

Comment: no it doesnt it connects but doesnt insert anything

Comment: Your Post method should take a parameter, the user model, that you are correctly sending through Angular. I hope that this example can help you: https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: i still dont get it

Comment: Follow some basic tutorials for ASP.NET Core Web Api then